# Should I install AMD Catalyst drivers or the open source drivers to play HoN?

Tags: drivers, games, amd-graphics

I always have issues while trying to play HoN (Heroes of Newerth) in Ubuntu. From what I see in the forums some folks have been able to run it flawlessly and it appears to be a driver issue. Now I reinstalled my system when 12.04 LTS came out and I haven't installed my video card drivers yet. Should I install ATI proprietary drivers or the open source drivers for best results?

My video card is ATI Radeon HD 5650.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say first try the proprietary drivers, they generally have the best performance, while the open source drivers are generally suited for non-demanding GPU tasks, at least that's the case with Nvidia.

Some people want to not be dependent on the hardware producer releasing and updating drivers, so they choose an open source one.

Comment: The difference between open-source and proprietary drivers is very different between AMD and Nvidia. So experiences with one aren't applicable to the other.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I reinstalled my system when 12.04 LTS came out and I haven't installed my video card drivers yet.

Im pretty sure Ubuntu comes with open-source drivers out of the box. So you should have those already installed. And therefore it would be wise to try how those work first and if it is unsatisfactory, *then* install proprietary ones.

Comment: Just FYI, this question was written in 2012, may be best to not waste time on questions this outdated ;)

Comment: @Mark Kirby: Yeah, i noticed. Just since i was reading it to research my own problem, figured other people might stumble upon it later looking for answers too. Not too much of my time spent. But thanks. :)

Comment: Sure and that is a good thing, just don't want you to expect a lot of voting on this old of a question :)